# How to use data that is not in the repository on BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: python, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

We are using Bitbucket for version control and we have two repositories. One (rep C) has C++ code that we re-compile rarely, and the other one (rep P) has Python code which calls the C++ code. This is where most of the work happens.

I want to set up pipelines so that when we push code in rep P, it runs all the unit tests.

My problem is that the python code requires the compiled C++ binaries of rep C.

Is there a way to set up BitBucket pipelines such that when we push code in rep P it compiles the code of rep C, so that the unit tests of rep P can use those binaries? Is it necessary to add the binaries and their libraries in rep P for that to happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a deployment key in rep C and add the key as an environment variable in rep P. Then, rep P is able to checkout the code from rep C and do whatever it needs/wants to do with it.

The checkout could either use a fixed branch such as “master”, or dynamically checkout a branch whose name is derived from `$BITBUCKET_BRANCH` in rep P.